# What do you call it when someone is polite after being rude?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call it when someone is polite after being rude? Like if somebody interrupted another person talking and then after talking for a long time, the person finally says 'may I please say something?'

Comment: Can you please clarify who is doing what? Like, somebody (person A) interrupted another person (B) talking and then after (A) talking for a long time, the person (B) finally says 'may I please say something?'

Comment: Being two-faced?

Comment: I would call it Britishness

Comment: Too vague/broad. There are many different scenarios in which someone is polite after being rude.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is an example of passive aggressive behavior, so the single word phrase is actually hyphenated:
"passive-aggressive"

Insulting someone and pretending not to know you have insulted them...

ie #1

Your mom is passive aggressive. She always acts sweet and then subtley mentions my three abortions in a matter of fact way.

ie #2

{I'm passive aggressive if I}

hide my hostility by seeming to be nice to someone I dislike, and am unable to be honest with the person.